# How can one specify multiple platform-specific plugin versions in an Ionic app (particularly dealing with cordova-plugin-email-composer)?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

Ever since the release of cordova email composer version 0.8.3, I've been having problems implementing it into my multi-platform (Anrdoid & iOS) app.  I was able to fix the Android side of things by specifying version 0.8.2 in `package.json` (`"cordova-plugin-email-composer@0.8.2",`), but this broke it on iOS.  I have seen suggestions to specify the plugin dependency in the `config.xml` file under the respective platforms, but this did not seem to work.  Regardless, I would prefer to use only one method to specify my plugin dependencies, and thus far I have been using `package.json` since I am using Ionic.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do strictly using `package.json` and Ionic, and if not, is there an Ionic-specific way of using the `config.xml` to do this?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would like to know if this is possible too.  I've been having issues using ngMask where I need to use a specific branch of the repo, but only for andorid not ios:
"ngMask": "git@github.com:candreoliveira/ngMask.git#a73544ca3a3a2b35558d25ad331235ff65c2fcb2",
ngMask issue: https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/issues/127